# How to avoid null values serialization in HashMap?

Tags: json, serialization, jackson

I would like to serialize a HashMap as a string through the Jackson JSON processor.
For example:

```
String strMap = getMapper().writeValueAsString(myHashMap);
result output -> {"r_id":6,"a_am":null,"smb":"Submit","a_li":null,"l_id":878,"pos":[1345,1346,1347]}
```

I don't know how to disable null values serialization for Map. It works fine only for POJO if configure the Jackson like this:

```
mapper.getSerializationConfig().setSerializationInclusion(Inclusion.NON_NULL);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For what it's worth, Jackson 1.6 will have this:

```
objectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, false);
```

which does do what you want. Existing method only works for beans, and is not being changed to ensure maximum backwards compatibility.

EDIT: as per note on comments, this is for Jackson 1.x; Jackson 2.x has matching `SerializationFeature`

Comment: And 1.6 was just released couple of days ago as well.

Comment: Now it looks like `mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, false)`

Answer (score 12):

Here is the latest annotation for ignoring the NULL fields

@JsonSerialize(include= JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)

Answer (score 7):

Using Jackson 2.1.2 I have found that I can annotate the class with
`@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` so that nulls are not serialized at all.

Comment: Whats the difference between this and with @JsonSerialize?

Answer (score 3):

Or you can annotate your bean with @JsonWriteNullProperties(false) which will

Comment: As of 1.?, use @JsonInclude(value=Include.NON_NULL)

Comment: It seems that @JsonInclude(value=Include.NON_NULL) is deprecated. So for beans add `@JsonSerialize(include=Inclusion.NON_NULL)` to the class to be serialized. Also see http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQ.

Comment: Where do you see that @JsonInclude is deprecated? It's explicitly listed at https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/JacksonAnnotations

Answer (score 2):

With latest Jackson version, on the ObjectMapper, you can do:

mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);