# How to prevent null values inside a Map and null fields inside a bean from getting serialized through Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a a `Map<String,Foo> foosMap` that I want to serialize through Jackson . Now I want following two settings on the serialization process:

1. The Map can have  have plenty of null values and null keys and I don't want nulls to be serialized.
2. For all those Foos that are getting serialized, I do not want to serialize null objects referenced inside Foo.

What is the best way to achieve this ? I am using jackson-core1.9 and jackson-mapper1.9  jars in my project.

Comment: Possible duplicate, please check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140563/how-to-avoid-null-values-serialization-in-hashmap

Comment: Map can have atmost one null key

Comment: @dbf not quite . please see the edited question title again.

Comment: @dbf  Also [that method](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-lgpl/1.9.7/org/codehaus/jackson/map/SerializationConfig.java#SerializationConfig) in the accepted answer seems to be deprecated now

Answer (score 128, accepted):

If it's reasonable to alter the original `Map` data structure to be serialized to better represent the actual value wanted to be serialized, that's probably a decent approach, which would possibly reduce the amount of Jackson configuration necessary.  For example, just remove the `null` key entries, if possible, before calling Jackson.  That said...

---

To suppress serializing `Map` entries with null values:

**Before Jackson 2.9**

you can still make use of `WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES`, but note that it's moved to [`SerializationFeature`](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html):

```
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, false);
```

**Since Jackson 2.9**

The `WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES` is deprecated, you can use the below equivalent:

```
mapper.setDefaultPropertyInclusion(
   JsonInclude.Value.construct(Include.ALWAYS, Include.NON_NULL))
```

---

To suppress serializing properties with null values, you can [configure the `ObjectMapper` directly](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.html), or make use of the [`@JsonInclude`](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.html) annotation:

```
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

or:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
class Foo
{
  public String bar;

  Foo(String bar)
  {
    this.bar = bar;
  }
}
```

---

To handle null `Map` keys, some custom serialization is necessary, as best I understand.

A simple approach to serialize `null` keys as empty strings (including complete examples of the two previously mentioned configurations):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;

public class JacksonFoo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Map<String, Foo> foos = new HashMap<String, Foo>();
    foos.put("foo1", new Foo("foo1"));
    foos.put("foo2", new Foo(null));
    foos.put("foo3", null);
    foos.put(null, new Foo("foo4"));

    // System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(foos));
    // Exception: Null key for a Map not allowed in JSON (use a converting NullKeySerializer?)

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, false);
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
    mapper.getSerializerProvider().setNullKeySerializer(new MyNullKeySerializer());
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(foos));
    // output: 
    // {"":{"bar":"foo4"},"foo2":{},"foo1":{"bar":"foo1"}}
  }
}

class MyNullKeySerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object>
{
  @Override
  public void serialize(Object nullKey, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider unused) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
  {
    jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("");
  }
}

class Foo
{
  public String bar;

  Foo(String bar)
  {
    this.bar = bar;
  }
}
```

To suppress serializing `Map` entries with `null` keys, further custom serialization processing would be necessary.

Comment: Just a caveat these directions are Jackson 2.0 specific (`com.fasterxml` vs `org.codehaus`).

Comment: @ProgrammerBruce - Is it possible to prevent null-field serialization for a specific class in the object mapper?
eg: Use the same object mapper to serialize class A and B, but only null-fields in class B are ignored.

Comment: @ProgrammerBurce - as the jackson has upgraded to 2.9, the WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES is deprecated. Do you know is there an alternative way to do the same?

Comment: I find the equivalent of WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES since 2.9: `mapper.setDefaultPropertyInclusion(JsonInclude.Value.construct(Include.ALWAYS, Include.NON_NULL))`

Comment: @AidenZhao - I have jackson 2.9.2. My IDE, Intellij IDEA does not show any method called "setDefaultPropertyInclusion" for com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 19):

For Jackson versions < 2.0 use this annotation on the class being serialized:

```
@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
```

Comment: FYI, this is deprecated, the accepted answer above has the latest annotation: @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)

Comment: Note that the JsonInclude annotation is not available if you are using Jackson 1.9.x in which case you will have to use the JsonSerialize annotation.

Comment: I confirm with Jackson 1.9.x the @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)  doesn't work. I'm importing this package:  org.codehaus.jackson.map

Answer (score 3):

Answer seems to be a little old,  What I did was to use this mapper to convert a `MAP`

> ```
>       ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, false);
> ```

a simple `Map`:

> ```
>           Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<String,Object>();
>             user.put( "id",  teklif.getAccount().getId() );
>             user.put( "fname", teklif.getAccount().getFname());
>             user.put( "lname", teklif.getAccount().getLname());
>             user.put( "email", teklif.getAccount().getEmail());
>             user.put( "test", null);
> ```

Use it like this for example:

> ```
>       String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(user);
> ```

Comment: Please add the output of the json.

Answer (score -1):

my solution, hope help 
custom ObjectMapper and config to spring xml(register message conveters)

```
public class PyResponseConfigObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {
public PyResponseConfigObjectMapper() {
    disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES); //map no_null
    setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL); // bean no_null
}
```

}