# Jackson - serializing a list containing null elements

Tags: java, jackson

I'm using Jackson 2.4 to serialize objects to JSON.
When I serialize a list of objects, having some elements are null, the result `JSON` string contains some "null" strings. 
How do I prevent `"null"` elements from being serialized? Is there any configuration for `ObjectMapper`? I have already set `"setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL)"`!

Here is my code :

```java
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
strings.add("string 1");
strings.add("string 2");
strings.add(null);
strings.add(null);
```

After serializing I got this :

```java
[string 1, string 2, null, null]
```

How do I get the JSON string without "null"?

```java
[string 1, string 2]
```

Comment: Why are you adding the nulls if you don't want them?

Comment: It's just an example, in some cases, a collection may contain null elements, I just want to know if Jackson is able to ignore null members in a collection, or I have to make the collection null-free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [@JsonInclude](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.html) annotation.

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
class Foo {
  String bar;

}
```

**Edit**

Also you can create your own serializer. 
For example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add("string 1");
        strings.add("string 2");
        strings.add(null);
        strings.add(null);

        ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.getSerializerProvider().setNullValueSerializer(new NullSerializer());
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(strings));
    }
```

NullSerializer.java

```
class NullSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object>
{
  @Override
  public void serialize(Object obj, JsonGenerator jsonGen, SerializerProvider unused) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
  {
    jsonGen.writeFieldName("");
  }
}
```

Will print

```
["string 1","string 2","",""]
```

then you can remove  jsonGen.writeFieldName(""); to print

```
["string 1","string 2"]
```

Comment: NullSerializer solves problem with null values in arrays, Include.NON_EMPTY solves skipping of keys with empty collections and keys with null values.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion of implementing a custom NullSerializer is a great idea, in my case I don't want all null values to be ignored (eg, outside collections) so with just a small tweak you can have both things working.

```
class NullSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object>{
    @Override
    public void serialize(Object obj, JsonGenerator jsonGen, SerializerProvider unused) 
  throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        //any null outside of a collection will be serialized (as long as SerilizationInclusion allows nulls)
        if (!jsonGen.getOutputContext().inArray()) {
            jsonGen.writeNull();
        }
    }
}
```

Using that custom NullSerializer, serializing following class:

```
class MyTest {
    public List<String> list = Arrays.asList("hello", null, "world", null);
    public Object goodNull = null;
}
```

Produces the JSON:

```
{ "list":["hello","world"], "goodNull":null}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using below

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
```

also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449211/how-to-prevent-null-values-inside-a-map-and-null-fields-inside-a-bean-from-getti) for more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent it by :

`@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
 private String checkNullThenSerialize;`

put this on Member declaration.

or you can put class level also like :

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
class CheckNullThenSerialize{
  private String fieldData;
  private String fieldNull;
}
```

You can also try `Include.NON_EMPTY` with `@JsonInclude` alter to `Include.NON_NULL`.

For `ObjectMapper` (**Any null field in any class serialized through this mapper is going to be ignored**):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

Look [Here's](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-null-fields) full details on this topic.