# Preventing null values in a map inside custom Bean from getting serialized through Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper, jsonserializer

I have a bean like

```
class CustomResponse<Type> {
  String f1;
  String f2;
  List<Type> rows;
}
```

Here the **Type** can be a custom bean having Map inside it. In this case, I want to make sure to not print null values inside that map.

For example: My CustomResponse object can be `new CustomResponse<Row>();`
where `Row` is,

```
class Row {
  Map<String, Object> keyValues;
}
```

I am using Jackson 2.5 and using ObjectMapper like

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
if (skipNullFields) {
  mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
  mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, false);
}
```

Now if I write `mapper.writeValueAsString(customResponseObj);`, in the final response, I see null values inside the List of rows variable: `rows`. At the same time, if I write `mapper.writeValueAsString(((Row)rows.get(0)).keyValues);` I don't see null values in the final Json response - as I am directly passing a Map here instead of nesting it inside another bean.

Can you kindly help me to make sure I don't see null values even when I write as `mapper.writeValueAsString(customResponseObj);` ?

**Note:**

1. I know this question is very similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449211/how-to-prevent-null-values-inside-a-map-and-null-fields-inside-a-bean-from-getti). But in that post, nesting a Map inside a bean doesn't seem to be handled.
2. I am using new ObjectMapper instance for every thread. Hence I am not sharing a single instance of ObjectMapper across threads causing any thread safety issues.